# my code does not execute the at first time? why?

Tags: c#

i have this code in my project that i do it with a help in this web site, my code check the datagridviewcheckboxcolumn checked state after that it checks another cell of datagridview with these to checks it execute a method, all my code is inside a button click.
this is my code

```
private void update_bt_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var current_year = DateTime.Today.Year;
    var last_year = DateTime.Today.Year - 1;
    for (int i = 0; i < dgv_student_update.Rows.Count; i++)
    {
        Func<DataGridViewRow, int, int> cellValue = (row, j) =>
        {
            int.TryParse(row.Cells["stg_id"].Value.ToString(), out j);
            return j;
        };
        DataGridViewCheckBoxCell chkchecking = dgv_student_update.Rows[i].Cells["result"] as DataGridViewCheckBoxCell;
        if (Convert.ToBoolean(chkchecking.Value) == true)
        {
            //check if cell[3] in each row equal to stage id (1=first stage).
            if (cellValue(dgv_student_update.Rows[i], 3) == 1)
            {
                sc.year_student_update(
                Convert.ToInt32(dgv_student_update.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value),
                dgv_student_update.Rows[i].Cells[2].Value.ToString(), 2);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

when i click button it does not execute the "year_student_update()" method but at the second click it do the job. anyone can help me please?

Comment: Are you using Visual Studio? WPF? WinForms? ASPX?

Comment: yes visual studio 2013. winforms

Comment: where is 'sc' defined?

Comment: sc is object of another class the "year_student_update()" method is inside this class, but the problem is not there iam sure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your method `sc.year_student_update(...` is inside the `if` condition `if (cellValue(dgv_student_update.Rows[i], 3) == 1)` and most probably that's not `true`. comment that `if` block and see if your method hits. If so, then you should check why your `if` block not satisfying.

Comment: when i put a messageBox for example inside the if in the place of the method it gives me the message with first click this mean that the two if's are ture, i'm the if is true.